# Combine two line charts into one. (access 2010)

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way I can combine 2 line charts into one in access and get a result looks like that:
[image]

The grade scale is from -2 to 6 (left side - blue line), and the probability scale is from 0 to 120 (right side - red line).

note that the month not necessarily the same in grade and probability

thanks,

Arik

Answer (score 1):

Using Access 2010

First add both sets of data to the chart. Next select the chart, next choose the property sheet and the Series Group tab. Select your second data set and choose New Group, OK. In the box below, select the second group and the position for the axis and choose OK.

[image]